# How to calculate rolling average in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like

```
idx,val
1,10
2,32
3,21
4,55
5,43
6,31
```

I have to calculate the rolling average of every 4 values. For example the output df will be

```
idx,avg_val
1,avg of val(idx[1-4] to idx[1]) => avg(10)
2,avg of val(idx[2-4] to idx[2]) => avg(10,32)
3,avg of val(idx[3-4] to idx[3]) ...
4,avg of val(idx[4-4] to idx[4]) => avg(10,32,21,55)
5,avg of val(idx[5-4] to idx[5]) => ...
6,avg of val(idx[6-4] to idx[6]) => avg(21,55,43,31)
```

What I am doing now is looping over each row and calculating with the generic formula as `avg(idx[i-4] to idx[i])`. I am looking for any pythonic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
df['avg_val'] = df['val'].rolling(window=4, min_periods=1).mean()
```

Comment: First 3 values coming as `NaN`.